# Pretty printing DTDs (Document Type Declaration)

Tags: diagrams, verbatim, xml, markup

I want to include a didactic, compact view of a DTD (Document Type Declaration) in my texts.

DTDs are used to define the set of tags and attributes of a XML/SGML document -- some sort of a grammar of the document.

Verbatim DTD are too verbose and ugly.

Is there any `\usepackage` for:

- DTD pretty-printing?
- or for DTD diagrams?

I don't mind loosing/hiding some DTD details.

Comment: What does DTD mean?

Comment: @Ignasi There are 8 such acronymns in the sphere of military and government alone... http://www.acronymfinder.com/Military-and-Government/DTD.html, but 42 such acronyms overall.  Perhaps the OP means "Document Type Declaration": http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Document+Type+Declaration

Comment: would fit the description "verbose and ugly" ;)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes et al, right "Document Type Declaration". I forgot to tell -- I will include it in the question.

Comment: @Florian, than you for comment!

Answer (score 8):

*If* it is [Document type definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) that you want, [Pygments](http://pygments.org) has support for it and produces a very neat output imo.

For LaTeX documents you can harness it easily with the `minted`-package, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{autumn}

\begin{document} 

\begin{minted}{dtd}

<!-- TEI P4 DTD. Generated 2004-07-15T16:23:29-04:00 by odd2dtd.xsl -->

<!-- 17.1.2: Certainty and uncertainty-->
<!--
 ** Copyright 2004 TEI Consortium.
 ** See the main DTD fragment 'tei2.dtd' or the file 'COPYING' for the
 ** complete copyright notice.
-->
<!ENTITY % certainty 'INCLUDE' >
<![ %certainty; [

<!ELEMENT %n.certainty; %om.RO;  EMPTY> 
<!ATTLIST %n.certainty;
     %a.global;
     target IDREFS #REQUIRED
     locus CDATA #REQUIRED
     assertedValue CDATA #IMPLIED
     desc CDATA #IMPLIED
     given CDATA #IMPLIED
     degree CDATA #IMPLIED
     TEIform CDATA 'certainty'  >
]]>  
<!-- 17.2: Responsibility for markup-->
<!ENTITY % respons 'INCLUDE' >
<![ %respons; [

<!ELEMENT %n.respons; %om.RO; EMPTY> 
<!ATTLIST %n.respons;
     %a.global;
     target IDREFS #REQUIRED
     locus CDATA #REQUIRED
     resp CDATA #REQUIRED
     desc CDATA #IMPLIED
     TEIform CDATA 'respons'  >
]]>  
<!-- end of 17.2-->
<!-- end of 17.1.2-->

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Note that you have to have `python` and `pygments` installed on your system and call LaTeX with `-shell-escape`.

[image]

Comment: If you add an image of the output, the quality of your answer will be much improved.

Comment: @Florian, thank you. I will study minted -- it helped (+1) -- much better then verbatim. Although TEI is a too violent example,  I need to work out some way of improving its readability.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, here is the [pdfoutput](http://natura.di.uminho.pt/~jj/stackexchange-tex/dtd.pdf) I obtained.

Comment: If you are not aware, you can edit your answer and literally include it in the answer, either as an uploaded image (preferred for archival reasons) or as a web pointer (which is what I did with jjoao's pointer).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks, I knew that, but was in a hurry. But I never knew why I can't upload pdf -- wouldn't this be the most obvious choice for a site like this?

Comment: @Florian, don't forget that the file types that can be uploaded are stack-exchange wide, and pdf can't be displayed nicely inline.